# Translating a seed file with globalize

Tags: database, translation, globalize

I am a complete newby to coding. I am trying to translate products for an online shop. I have created a seeds file for these products in English.

I have installed the globalize gem. I have included translates `:title, :product_type, :short_description, :long_description` in the product model. I also created a migration file adding translation tables.

However I don't understand how to add the translated products (in german) in the seeds file. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details.  Please tag with the database platform.